# How to post data to a mapquest table

Tags: mapquest

I'm trying to post data to a mapquest table and I've done everything according to their [API](https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/data-manager/data/upload-data)

Here is my json:

```
{
    "tableName": "mqap.jZ3uoAVablablabla_reported_points",
    "append": true,
    "returnResults": true, 
    "rows": [
        [
            {
                "mqap_geography": "POINT (-123.3141509 48.4647675)",
                "date": "2016-03-13T02:19:09.674Z",
                "email": "anna@gmail.com",
                "latitude": "48.47542496514236",
                "longitude": "-123.37663650512695",
                "message": "ss",
                "user": "a"
            }
        ]
    ]

}
```

Here is a screenshot of the table

[image]

And this is the response I get in Postman

```
{
  "failures": [
    {
      "reason": "Either no latitude/longitude was provided, or the other information was insufficient for geocoding at or near line #0 of input.",
      "row": ""
    }
  ],
  "append": true,
  "returnResults": true,
  "totalRows": 1,
  "tableName": "mqap.jblablabla_reported_points",
  "tableSize": {
    "raw": 8192,
    "readable": "8 KB"
  },
  "data": {
    "rows": []
  },
  "failureCount": 1,
  "rowCount": 0,
  "info": {
    "statusCode": 0,
    "copyright": {
      "text": "© 2015 MapQuest, Inc.",
      "imageUrl": "http://api.mqcdn.com/res/mqlogo.gif",
      "imageAltText": "© 2015 MapQuest, Inc."
    },
    "messages": []
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things I was missing:

1. The database NEEDS to have a geography object. So I added a latlong Geography object that I didn't end up using.
2. The format of the JSON should've been the following:

   ```
   {
   "tableName": "mqap.jZ3uoAVablablabla_reported_points",
   "append": true,
   "returnResults": true, 
   "rows": [
          [
          {"name":"user","value":user},
          {"name":"email","value":email},
          {"name":"date","value":date},
          {"name":"message","value":message},
          {"name":"latitude","value":latitude},
          {"name":"longitude","value"longitude},
          {"name":"latlong","value":"POINT(" + parseFloat(longitude) + " " + parseFloat(latitude) +")"}
          ]
       ]
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

The geography column should be in the table by default when the table is created: mqap_geography. This column is populated depending on information in other columns depending on their data type: Geography, [Latitude, Longitude], [Street, City,  StateProvince, PostalCode, County, Country], and FullAddress. The Latitude, Longitude columns in the table above are type String so they won't populate the Geography column.